# I cannot access array of UILabel in different functions in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to create an array of labels.  I already found what I thought was the answer to my question in another question on this forum.  The answer to it was:

```
private var labels:[UILabel]()

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labels.append(Lable00)
    labels.append(Lable01)
    labels.append(Lable02)
    labels.append(Lable03)
    labels.append(Lable04)

    // do stuff with the labels view
}
```

but when I try this in my program I cannot declare private var labels:UILabel outside of a function or I get an Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' error.

If I do it inside of an @IBAction function for a button, the error goes away, but I cannot access the array on another @IBAction function for a different button.  What am I missing?

Comment: Replace `private var labels:[UILabel]()` with `private var labels = [UILabel]()`

Answer (score 0):

You got the syntax wrong, use:

```
private var labels: [UILabel] = []
```

Comment: `private var labels = [UILabel]()` is more succinct

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes, but I prefer this syntax for consistency `var name: type = init` regardless of type.

Comment: Personal preference, of course, but I prefer to leave `: type` out of it when the compiler can infer the type

Comment: @AaronBrager I leave it out when it comes to variables, but for properties I prefer the explicit type, and the `: type` syntax is the consistent way (including computed properties). Also, with this syntax changing the initial value sometimes requires fewer changes overall (e.g., if the initial array is changed between empty and non-empty).